# A necessary and sufficient condition for ergodicity

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory, ergodic-theory

Let $(X,\mathcal B,\mu)$ be a probability space and $T\colon X\rightarrow X$ be measure preserving. I need to prove that $T$ is ergodic if and only if the following property holds:

> If $f\colon X\rightarrow\Bbb R$ is measurable and satisfies $f(T(x))\geqslant f(x)$ almost everywhere, then $f$ is constant almost everywhere.

Comment: Do you have any thoughts on this ? If you want advice on this forum, you should show what approaches you have tried. Or if you are stuck at something, please mention that.

Comment: Okay, so if the given condition holds, I can show that T is ergodic by considering the indicator function of an invariant set say $A$, but I am stuck in the other direction.

Answer (score 3):

> **Definition:** The set $A\in\mathcal B$ is *invariant* if $T^{-1}(A)=A$.
>
> **Definition:** $T\colon X\to X$ is *ergodic* if the measure of each invariant set is either $0$ or $1$.
>
> **Definition:** The set $A\in\mathcal B$ is *almost invariant* if $\mu(T^{-1}(  A  ) \Delta A)=0$.

We have the following result (see *Ergodic Theory wiht a view towards numbers theory* by Eiseidler and Ward, GTM.

> **Proposition:** If $T$ is ergodic and $A$ is almost invariant then $\mu(A)\in\{0;1\}$.

One direction is quite easy: assume that for all $f$ measurable satisfying $f(Tx)\geqslant f(x)$ almost everywhere we have that $f$ is constant almost everywhere. Take $A$ such that $T^{-1}(A)=A$. With $f:=\chi_A$, we get what we want.

Conversely, assume $T$ ergodic. For each real number $R$, define $$S_R:=\{x,\sup_{n\geqslant 1}f(T^nx)\leqslant R\}.$$
Each $S_R$ is almost invariant, so $\mu(S_R)\in\{0,1\}$ for each $R$. Define $R_0:=\inf\{R>0,\mu(S_R)=1\}$. Then $f=R_0$ almost everywhere.